# Substring of a global parameter ADF dynamic content

Tags: azure, pipeline, azure-data-factory, dynamic-content

"@{concat(split(string(pipeline().globalParameters.DATABASE), 'JERICHO_'), ' Data Warehouse Load', ' ',substring(utcNow(),0 ,10 ))}"

"@{concat(substring(string(pipeline().globalParameters.DATABASE), 8), ' Data Warehouse Load', ' ',substring(utcNow(),0 ,10 ))}"

The full global parameter is JERICHO_DEV. However I will be publishing this to different environments with different database names (although JERICHO_ will be common in all). Is there anyway to standardise the database name above so that it takes the part after the _ regardless of how many characters it is?

Comment: Hi @Christopher McHugh, you want to concat the global parameter like that and store it in a variable in ADF?, also could you please specify what issue you are facing in this process.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to concatenate the global parameter substring with custom names like that you can use an array variable for the custom names and generate different database names by using **ForEach activity**.

Please follow below steps **after creating the global parameter**:

- First create an **array variable** with the Set Variable activity and give all custom names list in that array for **example**:

  `["Data Warehouse Load","AZURE SQL DB","SERVERLESS SQL"]`

  ***Set variable activity:***

  [image]
- Then, connect this to a ForEach activity and give the items value as
  `@variables('dbnames')` and check the Sequential.
  ***ForEach activity:***
  [image]
- Now, go to activities inside the ForEach and drag **Append Variable activity**. Click on it and create a new array variable in the variables section and give your **dynamic content**.

  `@concat(substring(string(pipeline().globalParameters.DATABASE),0, 8),item(),' ',substring(utcNow(),0 ,10 ))`

  ***Append variable activity dynamic content:***
  [image]
- Now create another Set variable activity for the result array output and connect it with ForEach by creating new array variable and values like below. This is optional as I am creating this array for showing the output. You can use the array variable created in append activity as result.
  `@variables('res_variable')`

  ***Set variable activity for output:***
  [image]
- Execute the Pipeline and you can see the global parameter DATABASE name **common(JERICHO_)** in all the database names in the output.

  ***Output:***
  [image]